# Get specific cells from a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a numeric array sized 1000x1 which have values 0 and 1, called `conditionArray`.
I have a cell array called `netNames` with the same size (1000x1) and its cells contain string values (which are name of some circuit nets).
I want to extract net names which from `netNames` which their pairwise condition bit is 1 in `conditionArray`.
E.g. if conditionArray(100) is equal to extract its net name from `netNames{100}`.

Output of this process can be stored in an string array or cell array.
Are there any ways to do this operation with pairwise operations or I should use a `for` statement for this?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness protip: `[mcve]`: [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ah, neat. Cheers :)

Comment: Why does `netNames(conditionArray)` not work?

Answer (score 0):

You shall check out `cellfun` in Matlab anytime you want to manipulate each element inside a cellarray without using a for loop.

Comment: `cellfun` is also a loop

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have:

```
N = 1000;
% an array with 0s and 1s (this generates random 0s and 1s):
conditionArray = randi([0,1],N);
% a cell array with strings (this generates random 5-character strings):
netNames = cell(N);
netNames = cellfun(@(c)char(randi([double('a'),double('z')],1,5)), netNames, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

To extract the elements from `netNames` where `conditionArray` is 1, you can do:

```
netNames(conditionArray==1)
```

This uses [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) into the cell array.